# Incorrect page title in moderator nomination form

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-election

This is the "nominate yourself as a candidate" page that I see:

> [image]

While the header is correct:

> Editing Nomination for [name here]

The page title itself is wrong:

> Editing Info for [name here]

Can this please be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been implemented in build 2015.4.7.2448.